# In MAUI, how to customize the folder name where app's cache and data are stored?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

The app's cache and data directories in MAUI is: `C:/Users/{UserName}/AppData/Local/Packages/{GUID}_{hash}/{LocalCache/LoaclState}`

When I create a MAUI project, build and run it. A folder will be generated in `Packages/` named {GUID}_{hash} like `B4B241BA-CD04-4CE4-83ED-FD99159F72A0_9zz4h110yvjzm`

I want to find a way to avoid using GUID as the name of a folder. Because it makes it hard for me to discern which folder corresponds to which app.

I have tried to modify the property `ApplicationIdGuid` in .csproj. But it didn't work at all.

I have found some apps not use GUID as folder name, like `Bandisoft.com.15700C60EE320_dytvnjx3s1h08`, `TelegramMessengerLLP.TelegramDesktop_t4vj0pshhgkwm`, so I think there maybe someway to achieve that.

Comment: _"it makes it hard for me to discern which folder corresponds to which app"_ - why do you need to know?

Comment: this is the behavior of UWP apps, not MAUI

Comment: 1. I can understand the reason Microsoft decide to use GUID as folderName is to avoid different applications accidently have the same folderName. But when I'm developing an app, I need to do some check on the files generated by my app. So I visite the {GUID}_{hash} folder frenquently. But GUID is hard to remember doesn't it? So I want to rename the folder and avoid using GUID. @CodeCaster

Comment: 2. Actually, this is the behavior of modern flyout apps, both UWP and MAUI. @Jason

Comment: Create a shortcut

Comment: Haha, this may after all be accepted as a solution. @Jason